# How to add a new card / source to stripe customer account?

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I am using [stpaddcardviewcontroller](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/custom#stpaddcardviewcontroller) UI element to ask a customer to enter the new card information

```
let addCardViewController = STPAddCardViewController()
addCardViewController.delegate = self
present(navigationController, animated: true)
```

Above code will show the `UI` but after tapping on the Done button, I need to get the token (generated from the added card information) for adding a new card/source to the existing customer.

I am using the following delegate method to get the token from `stpaddcardviewcontroller` UI

```
extension viewController : STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate {

func addCardViewControllerDidCancel(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true)
}


func addCardViewController(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController, didCreatePaymentMethod paymentMethod: STPPaymentMethod, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {
    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

How can I receive the card token in delegate methods? So that I can pass to [Add Card API ?](https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/create)

Answer (score 1):

You get the PaymentMethod token in your `didCreatePaymentMethod` delegate.

Stripe-iOS (using your publishable key) cannot update Customers by itself. There are 2 options here:

1) Post the token to a backend server endpoint where you would use a Stripe API library (with your Stripe secret key) and attach the PaymentMethod to a Stripe Customer: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/attach

2) If you use Ephemeral keys on your iOS app allows you to attach a PaymentMethod to a Stripe Customer. The SDK handles it for you. 
Stripe-iOS actually offers prebuilt UI to handle this too such as STPPaymentOptionsViewController. You would need to refer to the "standard integration" guide here which uses STPCustomerContext: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/standard

Comment: Thanks for answering but I what parameter will give me payment token? I tried `paymentMethod.card.` there is no such parameter like a token in new API. 

Is it paymentMethod.stripeId ?

Comment: Correct, `paymentMethod.stripeID` will return you the ID of the PaymentMethod, such as "pm_123", which you'd attach to the Customer.

Docs for STPPaymentMethod: https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPPaymentMethod.html